# What is the first instance in which Mendeleev published a long-form table as compared with his 8-column table of 1869?

Tags: reference-request, chemistry, mendeleev, chemists

Mendeleev is famous for having published his first periodic table in 1869. This was a short-form or 8-column table.

He also published a number of 18 column periodic tables. I am asking for instances, dates, references for any such longer tables.

Comment: I don't think Mendeleev published any long forms of periodic table apart from the 8-column table. The first long form of periodic table was published in 1905 by Alfred Werner: https://imgur.com/eZKdGtJ. More here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B9780444535900000017?via%3Dihub